# Nothing is firing on SELECT change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if I'm just not seeing the problem from being up for waaaaay too long, or I'm just dumb, but I have a page that will have lots (20-30) select and input fields, and what I am trying to do is make it so that when a user changes a SELECT or INPUT field, it goes and submits the data to the database in real time.

I've tried almost every solution and example I've searched for on here, and I've spent more than a few hours on dozens of permutations. Clearly, I'm missing something (and for my own sake I hope its not super obvious).

I am using Bootstrap 4 w/ jQuery (Current)

```
    <div class=" row align-items-start" id="row-field-36">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-top:.25em;padding-bottom:.25em;">Incident</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" style="padding-top:.25em;padding-bottom:.25em;">
            <select name="t1-field-36" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" id="t1-field-36"1>
            <option value="0" selected>N/A</option>
            <option value="1"">1</option>
            <option value="2"">2</option>
            <option value="3"">3</option>
        </select>
<!-- begin script t1-field-36 -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#t1-field-36').on("changed.bs.select", function () {
            var field = "t1-field-36";
            var value = $(this).val();
            var arg = "1"
            var person = "12345678"
            $.ajax({
                url: "echo.php",
                type: "post",
                success: function(result){
                    $("#contentbody").html(result);
                },
                data: {
                    "person": person,
                    "field": field,
                    "value": value,
                    "arg": arg }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
<!-- end script t1-field-36 -->
```

What is supposed to happen is directs the field ID, value, person, and any args, back to another script on the server to do the actual work. Right now for diagnostic purposes, 'echo.php' is just printing out any values sent to it. I have no errors in the JS console, and nothing appears to be listening to events on these SELECT boxes.

EDIT - 1: I've also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1-field-36').change(function(){...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML was malformed and you were wrapping pieces of your option tags in strings. You also didn't provide a `contentbody` div. As a side note, even when providing code for a question, please be sure you close your element wrappings. Your `divs` were also not closed.

I don't know whether to chalk these things up to you pruning the code for the question, or whether they are actual errors in your markup. Therein lies the problem :)

As for `changed.bs.select` there are several tickets and inquiries that state that this has not worked as it should. Simply use the `change` event. This can be done through `.change(function() { ... })` **or** `.on("change", function() { ... })`. Both do work in the code I've provided.

Lastly, because you're waiting for an AJAX response you may not be getting the immediate results you're expecting. The following example will show that things do fire when set up this way, though with an AJAX call it may take a moment for the results to show in your `contentbody` div ( *assuming one exists* :) )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  $('#t1-field-36').on("change", function() {
  console.log("change event fired");
    var field = "t1-field-36";
    var value = $(this).val();
    var arg = "1"
    var person = "12345678"

    var result = value;
    $("#contentbody").html(result);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" row align-items-start" id="row-field-36">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-top:.25em;padding-bottom:.25em;">Incident</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" style="padding-top:.25em;padding-bottom:.25em;">
    <select name="t1-field-36" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" id="t1-field-36" 1>
      <option value="0" selected>N/A</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="contentbody"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Possible helpful note:

I'd like to call it an educated guess, but the truth is this is more opinion than anything. I would suggest *not* sending a database update request after *every change* that's being done.

This could work fine in a solo, toy project, but for anything else you're going to be causing a slew of requests that your server will need to respond to/process - not to mention any view updates. If this is more than a pet project, you're likely setting yourself up to.. well, half-heartedly DDos yourself in a manner of speaking, haha.

I would suggest, alternatively, to have updates be aggregated client side before the updates are processed. A.e. globbing as many changes into one request before sending it out ( if it's like a decision tree type situation, store as much logic client-side ), or if it's "live" information updating( like profiles or something ), try to periodically save in local storage, and at a lesser interval/when the user indicates they're exiting or have been idle, send out the updates. This is akin to Microsoft Word saving temporary changes in cache.

This is up to your model and yourself of course/ depending on what you're doing - but I've seen many attempts at instant updates. It's never efficient when you try to coordinate *all* DOM input events with updates and sometimes it has caused massive problems.

Comment: Thank you zfrisch - I didn't notice the extra quotes being output to the SELECT field. Your syntax for the JS part worked like a charm.

Comment: @JoshVogelgesang no problem!

Comment: zfrisch - For this particular project, its for a limited user base on an intranet server. I'll never have more than 100 people using it at once. It is used to record simple metrics into a database for review and reporting.